# Need help solving a task - laws of conservation (leptons, baryons, charge)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, standard-model, conservation-laws

We got a task from our teacher, a multiple choice task; and here it is:

Which of the following reactions is correct, considering the conservation laws?
Note: **We have only learned to use the conservation laws for Electric charge, Baryon number and Leptonic number.**

[image: The Tasks:]

However, i found out that **B** and **C** must be wrong regarding to those laws, and that **A** and **D** is both correct. But the task ask specificly about the correct answer, and i am stuck here. And please also, explain why one of them should be wrong, regarding to those 3 laws, only.

My teacher had problems solving it aswell, so it might be an error in the task itself.

Thankyou!

Comment: The answer that you have accepted below is incorrect. Look carefully at lepton number conservation in the proposed reactions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the comments for a correction on this.

<s>There is one more conservation law: energy. You don't have the velocities of the particles, but looking at A:</s>

$$\nu_e + p \to e^- + \pi^+ + p$$

There is a proton before and after, simplify:

$$ \nu_e  \to e^- + \pi^+ $$

Something that has almost no mass turning into two massive particles? That should raise any physicist's gut feeling flags.

Comment: Aaaaaaaah That makes ALOT of sense! Thanks alot, i have been thinking about that problem for a while. And yeah, i am aware of the other law, but the task specificly asked to use only those three. However, thanks for your reply, I will also show this to the teacher i had that lesson.

Comment: Would you have this possibility IF you had an enourmous velocity, then ? I am abit curious on how that could end up, and if it is possble to produce those two massive particles after a high-energy collision?

Comment: Possible? Yes. You have five particles, so more than enough degrees of freedom momentum-wise. But that would mean having a neutrino interact with a proton, that has a very low cross-section. Furthermore, $\sigma \propto 1/k^2$ (IIRC), so for very high velocities, the cross section is even smaller.

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but this answer is completely wrong. We *observe* this reaction which we describe as "quasi-elastic neutrino scattering with pion production". It does require that the neutrino is energetic. The correct answer turns on identifying the correct lepton numbers of the neutrinos and charged leptons.

Comment: Another note. In the MeV and low GeV energy range, neutrino--nucleon cross-sections are rising approximately linearly with energy, not falling. This is a consequence of the cross-section being dominated by the weak boson masses, which makes it unlike, say t-channel electron-nucleon scattering where cross-sections in this energy range *are* falling as $Q^2$ increases.

Comment: I'm not sure why you cancel the protons. It is precisely by colliding two particles that we can achieve high enough energies. This is not supposed to be a decay.

Comment: This is why you should not trust what people say on the internet... sometimes they screw up. Thanks for the corrections.